# Every time i try to use GOTO statement to repeat a loop my macro fails to compile

Tags: excel, vba, do-while, goto, repeat

for a project of mine i am trying to produce a macro in VBA the purpose of the GOTO statement is to repeat the Do while loop until it is forced to stop.

every time i try to run the program VBA for applications freezes and no error seems to be apparent can anybody suggest why this might be happening and if there are any fixes

```
Sub buses()
    test.Caption = Day
    Dim mytime As String 'intiger showing current time
    mytime = "string" ' testing perpus only

    Dim counter As Integer 'intiger value for counter
    counter = 1 'counter set at 0

    Dim record As Integer 'intiger value for record
    Jump

    Do While counter < 20 'repeat if statment untill counter reaches 20
    counter = counter + 1 ' upon repeating counter has increased by 1

    If mytime = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("mon A").Range("A" & counter).Value) Then
    'if current time = a time of due to arive bus then

    record = counter 'record value and counter value are the same

        V1F1.Caption = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Day).Range("A" & record).Value) 'display record information on screen
        V1F2.Caption = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Day).Range("B" & record).Value)
        V1F3.Caption = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Day).Range("C" & record).Value)

    record = record + 1

        V2F1.Caption = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Day).Range("A" & record).Value) 'display record information on screen
        V2F2.Caption = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Day).Range("B" & record).Value)
        V2F3.Caption = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Day).Range("C" & record).Value)

    record = record + 1

        V3F1.Caption = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Day).Range("A" & record).Value) 'display record information on screen
        V3F2.Caption = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Day).Range("B" & record).Value)
        V3F3.Caption = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Day).Range("C" & record).Value)

        Exit Do  'break do

    End If 'end if statment

    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now) 'wait 1 second

    Loop ' loop as a result of if stament not being executed

    GoTo Jump: 'repeat Do while

End Sub
```

Comment: There might be a typo in your code. The label should be followed by a ":". It is Jump: not Jump. Then: After executing Jump your counter is at 20! So the while loop will not be executed. It is executed only once, after that you have an infinity loop between Jump and Goto Jump. Move the Jump mark above the line setting counter to 1.

Answer (score 1):

How about moving counter = 1 after "Jump". Next time use a for loop.